# How to detect YTPlayerState in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtubeplayer

How can I get the YTPlayerState in objective c? I need to check the state of the video alone.

Comment: Have you not implemented the delegate `didChangeToState`?

Comment: I have implemented the didChangeToState. I am using the latest youtube video helper. But the YTPlayerState is an another new method.

Comment: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/cebd3ae9a6456155abfdbc0f3785e72ee02c41b4/Sources/YTPlayerView.h#L570

Comment: it gives you the `YTPlayerState` in the completion,  what's the issue?